# How to refresh an ad image in a page which is taken from google admanager module

Tags: google-analytics

How to refresh an ad image in a page which is taken from google admanager module,the image are drawn as iframe while seeing its source.can anyone explain or provide code to refresh it and to change the next ad without page load.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess this is prohibited by the terms of Google. If you won't have you account closed, you should check in which conditions you can do it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply yuvan.am new for this google analytics will you please tell me more about this ? am in urge to fix this ASAP.we cant able to refresh it from backend ?i mean using jquery or javascript ?

Comment: Check this answer, it will give some clues how to do it. But I will not be responsible if your Google account will be closed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/whats-the-best-way-to-reload-an-iframe-using-javascript